# Connect to second server API trough sockets

Tags: python, json, sockets, network-programming, tornado

I'm writing a project in Python that will have two diffrent (separate) apps.

1. A proxy (normal Python code, no framework)
2. A database with API to send/receive JSON (written in tornado 4.4 framework)

My project will do something like this:

1. In the database app you can add filters: 1 - anchor tags which you want to filter out a web page, 2 - URL patterns that you want to give 403 status.
2. The database app on a specyfic URL (api/send-to-world/filter_type/) serves a JSON with all the filters of a filter_type = filter_type (from above)
3. While accessing a web page, the proxy first gets the filters by catch a JSON on the URL above and then does the filter stuff
4. For statistics, the filtered content is send to the database API that receives a JSON (url: /api/receive-from-world/) and saves the content to the database.

To test the project I put the to apps on my localhost:

1. PROXY on port 8000
2. Database app on port 900

The project worked fine when the two apps where written thanks to Tornado framework but for personal reasons I want to make the PROXY a litte more low - level -> using sockets.

So to do this I've rewitten the Proxy app to a pure Python code and I got a little problem. The problem is that when I create a socket and I want to receive a JSON from the database API the database app gives me a 404 error (while if I access that URL on the database it works fine). I don't know what can be the problem.

My proxy class with the send_json and socket creation method:

```
class Proxy(object):
    u"""The PROXY class."""
    (...)

    def get_remote_response(self, host, port, data):
        u"""Method that creates a socket to the remote_address and gets the response.
        :param host: remote_host,
        :param port: remote_port,
        :param data: data to send.
        :return response: the response without the headers.
        """
        response_text = ''
        try:
            remote_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            print "Trying to connect to:%s : %s \n\n" % (host, port)
            remote_sock.connect((host, port))
            remote_sock.send(data)
            remote_sock.settimeout(0.5)
            while True:
                try:
                    response = remote_sock.recv(self.buffor_size)

                    if len(response) == 0:
                        break
                except socket.error:
                    break
                response_text += response
        except socket.error, msg:
            print str(msg)
        remote_sock.close()
        response = response_text[response_text.index('\r\n\r\n') + 1:]
        return response

    def get_filters(self, filter_id, **kwargs):
        u"""Method that gets a JSON with filters from the remote server
        :param filter_id: filter id.
        :return filters: list of filters from the remote server.
        """
        filters = list()
        remote_host = '127.0.0.1'
        remote_port = 9000
        request_url = 'http://%s:%s/api/send-to-world/%s/' % (remote_host, str(remote_port), filter_id)
        first_line_of_request = 'GET ' + request_url + ' HTTP/1.1\r\n'
        headers = {
            'Host': remote_host,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
        request = first_line_of_request
        for header in headers:
            request += '%s: %s\r\n' % (header, headers[header])
        request += '\r\n'

        print "request:\n", request
        response = self.get_remote_response(remote_host, remote_port, request)
        print "response:\n", response
        if response:
            data = None
            try:
                my_json = response
                data = json.loads(my_json.decode('utf-8'))
            except ValueError:
                message = 'Cannot parse JSON.'
                # self.send_error(400, message=message)
            filters = []
            for one_filter in data:
                filters.append((one_filter.get('filter_id'), one_filter.get('filter_name')))
        return filters
```

The binding, listening and accepting on the PROXY is done, so I think that I don't need to upload it here. If so, just say so :)

I've leaved the prints so you can see what is going to the database app:

The request:

> request:
> GET http://127.0.0.1:9000/api/send-to-world/2/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1
> Content-Type: application/json
> Accept: application/json

And the response:

> Trying to connect to:127.0.0.1 : 9000
> response:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/dave/.virtualenvs/teleV1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1446, in _execute
> result = self.prepare()
> File "/home/dave/.virtualenvs/teleV1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 2174, in prepare
> raise HTTPError(self._status_code)
> HTTPError: HTTP 404: Not Found

The logs from the database app while trying to get the filters:

> tornado working on port 9000
> WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET http://127.0.0.1:9000/api/send-to-world/2/ (127.0.0.1) 2.75ms

While I access it via the web browser it gives me the JSON.

So to sum up: How can I receive a JSON from my database app using a socket connection? I think that if the servers work on diffrent ports then the problem shouldn't be with the `host: 127.0.0.1`. If I'm wrong and I can't do some thing like this on one computer then please correct me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt this is the problem, but you said your database app listens on port 900, yet your proxy is connecting to port **9000**...

Don't include the protocol, hostname and port in the HTTP request headers, so change

```
request_url = 'http://%s:%s/api/send-to-world/%s/' % (remote_host, str(remote_port), filter_id)
```

to

```
request_url = '/api/send-to-world/%s/' %filter_id
```

For example to make your proxy fetch this article from stackoverflow.com:

```
remote_host = 'stackoverflow.com'
remote_port = 80
request_url = 'posts/43481916'
first_line_of_request = 'GET ' + request_url + ' HTTP/1.1\r\n'
headers = {
    'Host': remote_host,
    'Content-Type': 'text/html',
    'Accept': 'text/html'
}
request = first_line_of_request
for header in headers:
    request += '%s: %s\r\n' % (header, headers[header])
request += '\r\n'
response = self.get_remote_response(remote_host, remote_port, request)
```

Comment: My proxy is on 8000 and my database is on 9000 (a typo in 900, forgot one zero). I did this earlier and it works but I don't think this solves the problem. My main goal is to have to two separate apps working on two diffrent servers so I can't just leave the path in the URL only I would  need the schema, hostname and port (default 80) so I can communicate through the WWW. In this situation the two apps need to be on one host. Can I simulate the two servers situation on my localhost?

Comment: "So to sum up: How can I receive a JSON from my database app using a socket connection?" @Solay.gy appears to have answered this question. Your additional question is unclear.

Comment: It is a answer that won't work on two diffrent remote servers. For example I'll host a proxy on http://proxy.com:8080/ and my database on http://mylittledatabase.com/. This answer is a half answer in my opinion.

Comment: Sure you can still have the proxy running on a different machine than the DB. Your proxy calls get_remote_response() with a host and a port number like this:
    response = self.get_remote_response(remote_host, remote_port, request)
All I was pointing out is that the request must not include protcol, server and port number.

Comment: Ou, I understand. But then why while I try to connect for example to stackoverflow.com I get a schema, hostname, path in the request_line? Shouldn't it be the same situation? (I'm just curious)